# I feel a disturbance in the Force

Tags: discussion

It appears that SpiritRealmInvestigator's account has been removed. He was one of the most active users on both C SE and H SE.

Do the mods know if the user deleted his account, or if it was removed for some reason?

Comment: They deleted it themselves. I don't know why.

Comment: As a result, a lot of top users took a big hit in points this month.
Not that most people would care, but it will definitely definitely mess up the statistics, especially for those newer users that have suddenly shot up to the top of the list.

Comment: I'm curious about it myself but leaning to think that it was self deletion since I just checked that his Reddit user was deleted as well, though I don't know when.

Comment: @RayButterworth There is an informative [meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126471/625056) about it: different scenarios of how the staff+review+system can contribute to preserving / invalidating votes of a deleted user.  If this is a case of self deletion, I wonder why the votes wasn't preserved since this definitely counts as a disruptive event.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple, so SE staff specifically decided to invalidate the votes before allowing the self-deletion of the account. That seems especially strange in this case.

Comment: @RayButterworth maybe, maybe not.  I don't think the meta answer is a policy set in stone, nor a description of the policy/system algorithm.  Maybe an announcement will be produced later by the staff, similar to deleted BH.SE user Tony, although this case doesn't compare in scale, plus I have an instinct that SRL acts in good faith while he was still a user.  I look forward to some explanation from a moderator / staff in this meta question.

Comment: I was just wondering this question!

Comment: That’s why I lost all those points :)

Answer (score 4):

I got in touch with Spirit Realm Investigator. He felt the need to turn the page and focus time on other matters.

SRI's insightful questions and honest curiosity will surely be missed!

---

Re discussion in the comments, I thought the site's decision to wipe out thousands of votes, when a user self-deleted an account amidst no wrong-doing, was short-sighted.

Few want to go to the trouble of writing a researched answer if the answer will probably be ignored. SRI's tendency to upvote any sincere effort to answer a question encouraged participation. Mass-deleting votes sends the opposite message.

Comment: +1 Thanks very much for posting - this was my guess.

Comment: Thanks from me too, for posting this.  Although I'm still puzzled over his decision to delete the account instead of just leaving it dormant like Nathaniel or Caleb.  One day when I don't want to be active anymore I would follow their lead instead of deleting.  But I respect SRL's privacy for his reason and still thank him for his contribution.

Comment: Thank you for shedding light on the matter. I've been wondering what happened to SRI. I was actually considering asking a question here on meta about it but looks like someone beat me to it already.

Answer (score 1):

I, for one, eagerly await the report of the investigation!

[image: The Truth Is Out There]

Comment: Do we know if an investigation is ongoing by the staff?

Comment: @GratefulDisciple I've got no idea, I don't see what's so weird about a user deleting an account. I think the Community Managers might be popping in to the site a bit more than usual right now, but I can't tell who or why.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple I don't think any investigation is ongoing. As far as I can tell this was an ordinary self-deletion. We may never know why they decided to delete their account.